# ZF2 using Memcached for module config cache

Tags: caching, module, zend-framework2, memcached, config

Is it possible to use Memcached for caching Modules Merged Configs ?

I've been looking throw the code and it seems that a lot of classes needs to be extended/changed/overridden to accomplish this ...

is there a easier way ?

Comment: This is only kind of related but there is some great stuff in this talk about zf2 performace maximization and a section about module config. Well worth a watch. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwpGPlL8oZc&list=PL_aPVo2HeGF-7o9SPO5arFrAaU8bcIjba&index=25

Answer (score -1):

in your

```
application.config.php
```

do you try to enable those 3 lines :

```
'config_cache_enabled' => true,
'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
'cache_dir' => './data/cache',
```

it's set the cache for all config you have. Including in modules.

edit :
maybe this link can help :
[cache using memcache](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/10/06/zend-framework-2-using-caches-configuration-to-setting-up-cache-services/)

Comment: read the question again. i am using those configs, BUT as you can see from `'cache_dir' => './data/cache',` its using the file system BUT i want to store the merged module configs in Memcached...

Comment: i just saw this tutorial, i don't know if it's what you want :